# What Is the simplest way to compile FFMPEG on an Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, compilation

I need to execute FFMPEG with some options that are not included when I install using apt-get, so I need to re-compile it. What is the best/easiest way to do it?

I'm using a Ubuntu 8.04 Server.
The option I need to add is --enable libspeex1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the source package from ubuntu repository:

```
mkdir ~/ffmpeg 
cd ~/ffmpeg
apt-get source ffmpeg
```

Install packages required for compiling this package:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg
```

Modify the configure flags on your own:

```
cd */
vi debian/confflags
```

Then compile the modified package with the command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Now you should have a .deb package, that you can install with

```
sudo gdebi ffmpeg*.deb
```